# Change div image when hovering on list of links in separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to create a simple page with a header and footer anchored to the top and bottom of the browser window, with responsive content between. For the inner content, I'm using a flexbox wrapper with a list of links on the left (in its own div), and another div to its right with the images.

I have that much working, but now I'd like to change the image in the div on the right, depending on which link on the left you last hovered. Similar to http://department.nyc/ (click "clients" in the bottom left, and then hover over the list of links). Seems like javascript/jquery is the answer, but after countless searches, I still haven't been able to achieve what I want.

This is pretty much how I have the page pieced together:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <header class="header">Header</header>
 <div class="workWrapper">
  <div class="workText">
   <ul class="workList">
    <li id="ex1"><a href="#">Example 1</a></li>
    <li id="ex2"><a href="#">Example 2</a></li>
    <li id="ex3"><a href="#">Example 3</a></li>
    <li id="ex4"><a href="#">Example 4</a></li>
    <li id="ex5"><a href="#">Example 5</a></li>
    <li id="ex6"><a href="#">Example 6</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="workImages">
   <img src="#">
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.workList {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
display: flex;
min-height: 100%;
flex-direction: column;
}

.workWrapper {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex: 1;
align-items: center;
}

.workText {
float: left;
width: 30%;
}

.workImages {
float: right;
width: 70%;
margin-right: 100px;
background-color: green;

img {max-width: 100%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/symjcfsk/

Comment: What have you tried? The code you share is HTML+CSS, it would be helpful if you also added the JavaScript that you have tried so far, and where you are facing problems.

Answer (score 2):

It is possibly by many ways. For example, you could use `data-*` attribules of hovered link to store image URLs:

```js
$(".workList a").hover(function() {
  var s = $(this).data("img");
  $(".workImages img").attr("src", s);
});
```

```css
  .workList {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.workWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.workText {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.workImages {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <div class="workWrapper">
    <div class="workText">
      <ul class="workList">
        <li><a href="#" data-img="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">Example 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-img="https://www.socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png">Example 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="workImages">
      <img src="#">
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be almost exactly what I want. Is there a way to use image files instead of URLs? Replacing the URL with the path to my .PNGs doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MMags, use relative URLs to identify your image files. For example: `/images/myimage.jpg` or `../images/myimage.jpg`. If your images and the page are plased in same folder, use file name only. See [Relative URLs](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) article for details.

Answer (score 0):

One of the alternative to achieve this kind of affect is to make use of "mouseenter" and "mouseout" events. Something like this:

```
$(".workList").on("mouseenter",function(event){
     var list_elem = event.target;
     // your code to change the background image accordingly.
});
```

Similarly to restore the default image:

```
$(".workList").on("mouseout",function(event){
    // Restore the default image.
});
```

Further optimisation can be done by keeping track of the last image used for background so we don't change the image when hovering over the same link again.

Answer (score 0):

pure html & css can't do the job,you need import js,below is my demo
I use background-color simulate the img src changed style,unique function is very easy 
`

```js
var mouseover = function (index) {
   document.getElementById('workImages').className = 'workImages bgcolor' + index;
  }
```

```css
.workList {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .workList& >li {
    padding: 10px 5px;
 }
 .workList  a {
  width: inherit;
  display: block;
 }

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.workWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.workText {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
}

.workImages {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 100px;
  height:inherit;
  background-color: #E1BEE7;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
 }
.workImages.bgcolor1 {
  background-color: #CE93D8;
}
.workImages.bgcolor2 {
  background-color: #CE93D8;
}
.workImages.bgcolor3 {
  background-color: #BA68C8;
}
.workImages.bgcolor4 {
  background-color: #AB47BC;
}
.workImages.bgcolor5 {
  background-color: #9C27B0;
}
.workImages.bgcolor6 {
  background-color: #8E24AA;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <div class="workWrapper">
    <div class="workText">
      <ul class="workList">
        <li id="ex1"><a href="#" onmouseover="mouseover(1)">Example 1</a></li>
        <li id="ex2"><a href="#" onmouseover="mouseover(2)">Example 2</a></li>
        <li id="ex3"><a href="#" onmouseover="mouseover(3)">Example 3</a></li>
        <li id="ex4"><a href="#" onmouseover="mouseover(4)">Example 4</a></li>
        <li id="ex5"><a href="#" onmouseover="mouseover(5)">Example 5</a></li>
        <li id="ex6"><a href="#" onmouseover="mouseover(6)">Example 6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="workImages" id="workImages">
      <!-- use bgcolor instead of img for display-->
      <!--<img src="#">-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```